# Jssor load specific slide based on query string

Tags: jssor

Have a slider configured as a video gallery, i would like from other pages to access a specific video.
Is it possible based on a query string to configure the slider to show a specific slide?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify $StartIndex option.

```
var slideIndex = parseInt(getParameterByName("elt") || "0");

var options = {
    ...
    $StartIndex: slideIndex    //specify slide index to display at the begining, default value is 0.
    ...
};

var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to retrieve the querystring

```
    function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
```

then when creating the slider

```
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
        var slideIndex = getParameterByName("elt");
        (slideIndex != "") ? jssor_slider1.$GoTo(slideIndex) : jssor_slider1.$GoTo(0);
```